# Max elements in a Mutable Array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I'm retrieving some data from a Parse DB and adding a string of the object to a mutable array initialised before, but it stops adding elements when it has 100 elements, is it possible to make the array larger? If yes, how?

**EDIT:**

The array of objects retrieved from Parse is also 100 elem, but in the DB there are more than 100 objects with the key: "Nom"

Code for the query:

```
NSString *parseClassName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ParseObjectDefault"];
    PFQuery *queryDades = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:parseClassName];
    [queryDades whereKeyExists:@"Nom"];
    [queryDades findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            for (PFObject *corredor in objects){
                NSString *nom = [corredor objectForKey:@"Nom"];
                [self.corredorsNomArray addObject:nom];
                NSString *dorsal = [corredor objectForKey:@"Dorsal"];
                [self.corredorsDorsalArray addObject:dorsal];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error:%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

**SOLUTION:**

Parse limit is by default 100 so I had to change the query limit like this:

```
queryDades.limit = 1000;
```

Comment: why could the array stops adding element after 100 objects? is there any error message, execution stops, hangs whats the status after 100 objects are added?

Comment: Can you qualify what "stops adding" means? The implication is that you never see more than 100 items? Are you sure you are not loading in batches of 100 and clearing your array each batch or something else. I doubt very much the problem is the array itself. Perhaps you should show all the code around what you already posted and explain what is happening in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse default limit is of 100 objects. Check your array size. You can make the limit maximum to 1000.

Comment: So the problem is that Parse only retrieve 100 elem?

Comment: yes, it seems like. Because by default parse return only 100 objects

Answer (score 0):

Max elements that a `NSMutableArray` can hold, well as the method `- (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` on 
`NSMutableArray` instance takes an `unsigned int` as an argument. So whatever the maximum value of an `unsigned int` on the targeted machine is the theoretical limit of the objects that could be added in array. However the actual limit is more likely to depend on the amount of memory available.

**Note** : You should also review your code if there is something which is responsible for the 100 objects limit of an array